# sorting collection of values from a text file and saving sorted values back to text file with pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, bigdata

I am trying to sort a textfile with records in following format
input.txt:

```
b1 xy
a2 pq
```

This is my pySpark code:

```
distFile = sc.textFile(input.txt)
words = distFile.map(lambda x: [x[:2],x[2:]])
words.saveAsTextFile("output")
```

And this is what I am getting as contents of the output

output/part-00000

```
[u'a2', u'pq']
[u'b1', u'xy']
```

I want the contents to be :

```
a2 pq
b1 xy
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also I get garbage values when I use `words.saveAsPickleFile("output")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to merge all your `strings` into one. Something similar to:

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize([("Roger", "Andrew"),
                      ("Melissa", "Goldsmith")])

words = rdd.map(lambda (n, ln): n + " " + ln)

words.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("output")
```

This is the result:

[image: How it looks]